# How do save a PHP variable $SAddress1 = "1234 My Address " for Use 3 pages later on a website in a form field? Apache, PHP, MySql website

Tags: php, mysql, apache

In the first page I scan some info and do the following to make $Saddress1 and $SelectedAddress1 = "1234 My Street" like so    THIS ALL WORKS NO ISSUES

And I now have $Saddress1 = 1234 My Street AND $SelectedAddress1 = 1234 My Street

On the same page I run a PHP Function that goes and gets a list of folks that match $Address1 from mysql and return to me a "document..." list to chose from. After you chose, it replaces $SelectedAddress1 with the address in the database record.  THIS ALL WORKS NO ISSUES

Then I submit OR post to a second page to choose which address I want to use but .... This is the issue:

$Saddress1 has no value when I get to the second page. I know I need to do a Session, or cookie or jquery or something - but, with all the reading in the world (and there is allot of it), I can't find one that uses PHP to write the value to someplace that can be used later on OR has a consensus that this is a good answer and works with things like "this little string goes in your  and this little script goes in your Body or Head , and this little script uses Jquery and goes HERE on your page, and when your done, on page 2 or 99 of your website, $SAddress1 with be "1234 My Street" and you can use it in a FORM like "This", or call it in PHP "Like This" or ...

I am new but think it should be fairly simple to save some info to a file, and then later on, call it up to use without 3 different languages and scripting styles .. but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right, you can use a `<form>` to pass along values from one script to another. Or you can pass along the values through the URL, `mysite.com?key=value&key2=value2`...

Comment: What has this got to do with Java?

Comment: If I use FORM - and someone chooses another name after the first one cause they messed up - when I get to the second page "1234 My Street" is gone.

Comment: I don;t knwo that it has anything to do with Java - I am asking How to save a variable from PHP and have it available for use in later pages. Maybe Java? Maybe Sessions, Maybe Cookies but if any of them, how do I write "1234 My Street" to somepalce to use 2 pages later in a Form?

Comment: As you said, you can use PHP session, database, query strings. All kind of depends on what techniques you're currently using. I'd say sessions are your best bet. But you haven't provided any code explaining the way you're doing it so can't really help further.

Comment: ElernalHour - its a question of how to do it, not looking for someone to type my exact need. How would to write a variable someplace (that starts out as a variable a PHP script created, to be used 2 or 3 pages later in a Form, or another script, or? AND btw, not just one field, 9 of them. All the research shows how to write like Session = "My Text" bu tdoes nto show how to $myvariable instead of "My Text" now does it show how to ad the second variable and 3rd, and then once you write it, how do you use it in the form, is it "myvariable or ["$myvariable"] - "How to make a PP$J Sandwich"

Answer (score 1):

In the php file (server side), where you receive the form field ($Saddress1) for the first time. Ensure you have this line at the start of the code:

```
session_start(); //this initializes the session system in php
```

Then make sure when processing the POST or GET input in this php file, you save the field into the SESSIONS storage like this:

```
$_SESSION['Saddress1'] = $Saddress1;
```

From now on, until the user closes the browser, you can always echo the Saddress1 variable like:

```
echo $_SESSION['Saddress1']; //make sure you session_start() at the start of all the files that you will be using/echoing this value in, else $_SESSION['Saddress1'] will be empty.
```

Comment: Forgot to come back and let you know - this worked perfectly - thanks!